# Как изменять контент всплывающих окон в зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажата?

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько элементов и по клику на них должно открываться всплывающее окно.Окна одинаковые, единственная разница в том, что в зависимости от того, на какой элемент нажали, меняется контент всплывающего окна.
Кто подскажет как это реализовать на js?
Понимаю что это примерно как с табами, но на табах уже изначально на одном элементе стоит active и делается через флаги.
Модалку вызываю таким образом

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.share__desc-popup').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
      $('.popup__call').fadeIn();
});


$('.popup__close').on('click',function(){
  $('.popup__call').fadeOut();
});

  $(this).keydown(function(eventObject){
      if (eventObject.which == 27){
        $('.popup__call').fadeOut();
      }
  });
$('.popup').on('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.closest('.popup__wrap') == null) {
    $('.popup__call').fadeOut();
  }
});

});
```

Сама модалка вот

```
<div class="popup popup__call">
  <div class="popup__dialog">
    <div class="popup__wrap">
      <div class="popup__content">
        <div class="popup__close">
          <div class="popup__close-btn"></div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="popup__header">
                     Блок</h2>
                <div class="popup__desc">
                    <p>
                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum temporibus vel minus aliquam vitae error adipisci labore, consectetur sequi veritatis beatae iste? Odio tenetur sit ullam ducimus quia labore culpa!</span>
                        <span>Quam rem molestias facilis. Consequatur et minus deserunt harum aperiam recusandae cum voluptates voluptate, architecto aliquid assumenda ratione id neque perferendis eos ut inventore obcaecati accusantium ex labore expedita rem.</span>
                        <span>Dignissimos asperiores consectetur ratione quos? Laboriosam, animi magni quibusdam id commodi incidunt, quia ut autem nisi doloribus earum deserunt! Hic assumenda quaerat vel vero adipisci numquam, nisi aut ipsam repudiandae!</span>
                    </p>
                </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот элементы по клику на которые нужно чтобы выплывала модалка и в зависимости от того какая разная

```
<div class="card__info" id="cardInfo">
                                <h4 class="card__mini-title card__mini-title_margin_bottom">информация</h4>
                                <ul class="card__info-list">
                                    <li class="card__info-item" data-item="1">
                                        <div class="share__desc-wrap share__desc-popup">
                                            <svg class="share__desc-icon">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icon/sprait.svg#circle"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__info-text">Круг</div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="card__info-item" data-item="2">
                                        <div class="share__desc-wrap share__desc-popup">
                                            <svg class="share__desc-icon">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icon/sprait.svg#card"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__info-text">Кредит</div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="card__info-item" data-item="3">
                                        <div class="share__desc-wrap share__desc-popup">
                                            <svg class="share__desc-icon">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icon/sprait.svg#cub"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__info-text">Доставка</div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="card__info-item" data-item="4">
                                        <div class="share__desc-wrap share__desc-popup">
                                            <svg class="share__desc-icon">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icon/sprait.svg#reverse"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__info-text">Обновить</div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="card__info-item" data-item="5">
                                        <div class="share__desc-wrap share__desc-popup">
                                            <svg class="share__desc-icon">
                                                <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icon/sprait.svg#shield"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__info-text">Защита</div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

Comment: *Как изменять контент* - какой контент, откуда вы его берете, в какое место не получается вставить? `$('.popup__call .popup__desc').text('Ваш контент');`

Comment: Получается нужно изменить его в заголовке модалки и в описании(контентной части).
А откуда беру, можно либо со стороннего файла, либо уже в коде вставить сразу модалки соответствующие.

Answer (score 0):

Всем "табам" присвойте одинаковый класс, но разные айди. Например: `class="tabs" id="tab_1"`
Далее получаем все "табы" по классу:

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
// проходим по циклу:
for(var x=0; x<tabs.length;x++) {
    if(tabs[x].id == "tab_1") {
        // меняем контент на нужный
        tabs[x]....}
    else {
        // скрываем или что-то другое 
        tabs[x]...
    }
}
```

`onclick()` думаю добавите сами